# Slash not point back at a directory with htacess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, path

```
<link href="/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can i make this point to `css/screen.css` with help of .htacess? and everything else also, so that it wont point back!

Comment: Looks like it's already pointing to "css/screen.css"

Comment: it points back to root. So i want localhost/myproject/css/screen.css but it points to localhost/css/screen.css

Answer (score 0):

> it points back to root. So i want localhost/myproject/css/screen.css but it points to localhost/css/screen.css

Remove the `/` from the reference so that it's a relative URL:

```
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: All my links are created dynamically, and i have only access to htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .htaccess for this, just give proper absolute path.
If your above file is in root directory then just write

```
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If its inside some folder then

```
<link href="../css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And do this for all references you using.

Read this, might give you some basic idea about [absolute path](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm).